# How to handle multiple select tags using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 drop down options that are select tag. When I select an option from the first drop down menu, some divs will hide. The problem is that if I select an option from the second drop down, other divs will hide based only on the second rule. But I also want to respect the first rule.

For example. I have a repetitive div for each project in my DB. First drop down has 3 option for severity. Minor, medium and major. If I choose Major, right now only the Major projects are shown and others are hidden. The second select tag filters the type of project. If I leave the first filter with Major, when I select an option for the second select, the divs will show/hide respecting only the second rule. But I want to combine the rules of the selects.

```
<select id="chooseSeverity">
        <option>Choose Severity</option>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < countBySeverity.size(); i++) {
        %>
        <option value="<%=countBySeverityColumn.get(i)%>"><%=countBySeverityColumn.get(i)%></option>

        <%
            }
        %>
    </select> <select id="chooseType">
        <option>Choose Type</option>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < countByType.size(); i++) {
        %>
        <option value="<%=countByTypeColumn.get(i)%>"><%=countByTypeColumn.get(i)%></option>

        <%
            }
        %>
    </select>
```

These are two of my four selects. And these are my jQuery rules.

```
$("#chooseSeverity").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                var val = optionValue;
                $(".status").each(function() {
                  var parent = $(this).parents('.style2'),
                    length = $(this).text().length > 0;
                  if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, "i")) < 0) {
                    parent.fadeOut("slow");
                  } else {
                    parent.show();
                  }
                });
            }
            else{
                 $(".status").each(function() {
                     var parent = $(this).parents('.style2');                         
                     parent.fadeIn("slow");
                   });
            }
        });
    });

    $("#chooseType").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                var val = optionValue;
                $(".savingType").each(function() {
                  var parent = $(this).parents('.style2'),
                    length = $(this).text().length > 0;
                  if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, "i")) < 0) {
                    parent.fadeOut("slow");
                  } else {
                    parent.show();
                  }
                });
            }
            else{
                 $(".savingType").each(function() {
                     var parent = $(this).parents('.style2');                         
                     parent.fadeIn("slow");
                   });
            }
        });

    });
```

How to combine all the rules?

Thanks.

PS: Here is the minimal fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjho75jp/1/

Comment: Don't show us the ASP code, show us the rendered HTML.  Also, simplify to the smallest example required to demonstrate the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @cale_b excuse me. Here you have a minimal fiddle with my work. Thanks: https://jsfiddle.net/zjho75jp/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Getting Select List Values](http://marcgrabanski.com/jquery-select-list-values/)

```
var foo = []; 
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
});
```

Comment: Useless answer.  No explanation of what you've done or how it helps.

Comment: @cale_b Sorry I was going through some jquery Tips i have provided a link at the top, i thought i might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, this is not helping me. Because my dropdown is not an multiple choice. I have multiple selects each one with only one answer.

Comment: do you really need to convert `selected` into a jQuery object again? it is already a jQuery object, so no need to say `$(selected).text()` you could just say `selected.text()`